# Phonegap iOS getting this error : the password for the associated certificate is incorrect

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, p12

Hi I'm trying to build an ios app from phonegap builder and I'm getting this error : the password for the associated certificate is incorrect

I'm user a p12 basic password with no special characters

What could be the problem ?

[image: the password for the associated certificate is incorrect]

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the padlock, next to the key name in the dropdown, you should be asked for the **certificate** password. Ensure you have entered that correctly and not any other password.

There are many, many steps to go through to build & run on iOS. It is easy to make a mistake.

Android is so easy - just build and run :)

Answer (score 0):

When you export the p12 file, make sure to select both the private key **and** the certificate.

[image]

Comment: @Alpha Could you please pick an accepted answer so we can close a bunch of other answers as duplicates of this one? Thanks.

Comment: Finally got it to work.  What you say is correct, however, it's easy to pick the wrong key.  What I found was better was to click on "Certificates" in the Keychain, so you can see the Key underneath it.  Export the Certificate at this level will also export the private key under it.